# Multi-line IDL command from a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface, idl-programming-language

I'm wondering how to call a multi-line IDL command from a shell script. For example, to call a one-line command idl_dummy.pro I can do:

> idl -e "idl_dummy"

I have a set of codes that take more than one line to execute in IDL. Within IDL I need to run:

> .comp /a_different_directory/idl_file.pro
>
> ans = idl_dummy(123456)

How can I run this code from a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' IDL_SCRIPT <<EOF
  .comp /a_different_directory/idl_dummy.pro

  ans = idl_dummy(123456)
  ; print, ans ;?
EOF

# Print the script out for debugging
echo "${IDL_SCRIPT}"
idl <<< "${IDL_SCRIPT}"
```

or

```
idl <<< \
  "!path = EXPAND_PATH('/a_different_directory/:' + !path) & \
  idl_dummy, 123456"
```

You might have to play around with `!path` to automatically compile the code you need.  I'd also recommend naming the procedure so you don't have to manually compile with `.comp` (as I suggested in the answer).

Comment: You probably want `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`, unless you want shell expansions to take place in your script (`$foo`, `$(foo)`, etc to be replaced).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, sometimes that is desired (e.g., the script is in a function that is called by GNU Parallel) but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks @sappjw! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put your two commands in a file with a `.pro` extension, say `test_batch.pro`. This is a batch file; it cannot use `begin`/`end` blocks, but doesn't need any special syntax.

Then call IDL like:

```
$ idl path/to/test_batch.pro
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! If possible I'd love to avoid such a wrapper script, but if that's the best way to do it I guess I have no choice!